# update vs. insert

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, innodb

We are using innodb and have a table that will have many millions of rows.  One of the **columns** will be a `varchar(32)` whose value will change fairly often.  Doing updates to this `varchar` on tens of thousands of rows will take a long time, so we are trying with the idea of splitting this field off into its own table and then instead of doing updates, we can do a delete followed by a batch insert using load data in file. 
 It seems like this will greatly improve performance.  Am I missing something though?  
 Is there an easier way to improve update performance?  Has anybody done anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

If you can select the rows you want to update based on indeces alone this should in practice do the same as your suggestions (and still keep a sane data organization, hence be preferable). Quiet possibly this is even faster than doing it yourself.

Comment: The rows we will update or insert will be based on indexed ids.  The way i am proposing there is no lookup at all though because we have all the ids before we do the inserts (see comment on other post).  I cam to this possible solution because I was noticing that updates take a long time compared to inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an index appropriate to the where clause of your update statement.

The idea of splitting it up may improve performance (I'm not sure), but only, when all values change at once. When individual values change, this approach is slower than the approach with one table.

Another precondition for being faster is, that you must know the key->value mapping of the second table beforehand. If you have to look into the first table for deciding how to store values in the second one, you are also slower than with one table.

Comment: We will have the key value pairs already.  Basically we do a query to see what ids we need to get the value for, then we go off and get the values (i.e. not in sql, just some external source).  Once we get all of the values we then have a large set of id/value pairs.  My thinking is that if we use a separate table for this stuff then we can just do a delete where id in (...) then do a bulk insert of the id/value pairs.  This avoids an index lookup for each update statement.  And we can use a load data infile which is very fast.